# How can I sync notes from the Mac OS Notes app to plain text?

Tags: macos, notes.app

I'd like to sync my notes in the Mac OS (Mountain Lion) Notes app to plain text files. E.g., if I have a note called "shopping list" in the Notes app, I'd like to find a way to automatically export this to, say, shopping_list.txt. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Export or sync?

Comment: Sync. Do you know how to do either?

Comment: You can't sync with a text file. Does it have to be Notes.app at all (there are other notes-like apps out there)?

Comment: I think the OQ is about exporting the original `Notes` format to plain text files.